# How to find length of an element in a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm just starting with programming. I have a list of a few strings and now I need to print the biggest (in length) one.
So I first want to just print the lengths of elements. I was trying things like this:

```
l = ("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyy","zz")

for i in range(len(l)):
```

So how do I do it?

Comment: Actually it's a tuple.

Comment: -1: The fragment won't even work as it is.  The syntax is wrong.  Please fix the fragment so it at least could run.

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
l = ("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyy","zz")
print(max(l, key=len))
```

First of all you don't have a list, you have a tuple. this code will work for any sequence, however; both lists and tuples are sequences (as well as strings, sets, etc). So, the `max` function takes a `key` argument, that is used to sort the elements of an iterable. So, from all elements of `l` will be selected the one having the maximum length.

Comment: but it does not give a string occurrence 2 with same max length

Answer (score 9):

To print the lengths of the elements:

```
elements = ["xxxxxx", "yyy", "z"]
for element in elements:
    print len(element)
```

I recommend you read some tutorial material, for instance http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Comment: The question asks to print the largest string.

Comment: @Amit: The question states "So I first want to just print the lengths of elements."

Answer (score 5):

For those who are here because they want to measure the lengths of all the elements in a sequence(list,tuple, etc) and return those lengths into another sequence (list, tuple etc), do this:

**TLDR**

```
list_of_lengths = (lambda x:[len(i) for i in x])(lst)
```

**Longer explanation** (from the inner brackets, moving outwards)

1. We loop through our list and get the corresponding length value of each element using the len() function which is inbuilt into Python.

```
[len(i) for i in x]
```

2. Create a temporary function to wrap the looping operation in the previous point so that any list can be put into the function and its element lengths returned.

```
(lambda x:[len(i) for i in x])
```

3. Call the function using our list as the argument by putting it in brackets next to the function definition.

```
(lambda x:[len(i) for i in x])(lst)
```

4. Assign the newly created list to variable so that you can use it for other operations (like finding the largest/smallest element or its index as seen in the question asked on this page.)

```
list_of_lengths = (lambda x:[len(i) for i in x])(lst)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> sorted(['longest','long','longer'],key=len)[-1]
'longest'
```

UPDATE: SilentGhost's solution is a lot nicer.

Answer (score 3):

just ask for the max according to the length

`print max(["qsf","qsqsdqsd","qs"], key = len)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print the largest string in the set:

```
l = ["abcdev", "xx","abcedeerer"]
len_0 = len(l[0])
pos = 0

for i in range(0,len(l)):
        if len(l[i]) > len_0:
                pos = i
print l[pos]
```

Comment: Why the -1? I gave the answer to "now I need to print the biggest (in length) one".. .

Comment: While I'm sure your solution works, it is not a good example on how to write Python code. To someone asking for help about Python, it's simply not helpful.

Comment: I probably wrote C there. Do you recommend using more Python constructs, like 'max...key' ?

Answer (score 0):

This code maps "len" function over the list, to get another list containing the length of every item.

```
mylist = ("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyy","zz")
len_mylist = map(len, mylist)
max_position = len_mylist.index(max(len_mylist))
my_item = mylist[max_position]
print('The largest item of my list is: ' + my_item)
print('located at position: ' + str(max_position))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all to find the length of strings you can define the function and use map function  as below:

```
def len_words(l:list):
    len_list = list(map(len,l))
    return len_list
```

After that you can call the max function on len_words to find the maximum value of string from list.

```
max(len_words(l))
```